# Regex phone number to accept +

Tags: regex

I'm implementing a validator function in a form that has this regex `/^[\d\s ().-]+$/` for phone numbers.

I would like to change it to accept a starting `+` and then all combinations of `[0-9]` `.`  `-` `,` `(` `)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's pretty easy. Don't forget to escape the "+". I assume the "+" is optional, thus use the `?` quantifier.

```
/^\+?[0-9(),.-]+$/
```

Comment: `\+?` makes `+` optional.

Comment: I know and said it in the answer.

Comment: @491243: The problem relies in our definition of "accept". It can mean you *expect* a starting "+", or *allow* the user to start the string by a "+". Either way, it's no big deal, the OP will choose to add the `?` or not.

Answer (score 5):

since you want to start with `+`, you need to tell the engine to start with `+` by escaping it since it has another meaning,

```
/^\+[\d\s ().-]+$/
```

the answer simply answers what you ask but the it does not give you proper result since it will match with `+...,..()`, *I can modify this if you can specifically tell us the acceptable patter you want, eg +639151234567*

Answer (score 0):

Below regex can match any type of number, remember, I have assumed `+` to be optional.
However it does not handle number counting

```
^\+?(\d[\d-. ]+)?(\([\d-. ]+\))?[\d-. ]+\d$
```

Here are some valid numbers you can match:

```
+91293227214
+3 313 205 55100
99565433
011 (103) 132-5221
+1203.458.9102
+134-56287959
(211)123-4567
111-123-4567
```

Comment: You're adding rules the original regex didn't have (e.g regarding parenthesis), so you need to explain them in your answer.

Comment: being a simple regex, what to explain, hah !
i didn't do any extraordinary thing, it's just what the user wants :)

Comment: Indeed, it's a simple regex... Except when you're still learning regexes. :) Explaining the regex will be at least useful for the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is the best I can come up with. I merged many of the regex given in other answers.

```
/^[+]?(1\-|1\s|1|\d{3}\-|\d{3}\s|\d{2}\-|\d{2}\s|)?((\(\d{3}\))|\d{3})(\-|\s)?(\d{3}) 
(\-|\s)?(\d{4})$/g
```

This should support all combinations like

1. (541) 754-3010
2. +1-541-754-3010
3. 1-541-754-3010
4. 001-541-754-3010
5. 191 541 754 3010
6. +91 541 754 3010

and so on.

Comment: Please don't post multpile times the same answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59734390/372239 https://stackoverflow.com/a/59735221/372239 https://stackoverflow.com/a/59735305/372239